# Hash router works in production but browser router doesn't in react webpack app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-router-v4

I am working on React App using a custom webpack boilerplate and I want to access the browser router. It's not working on the production environment where it redirects to the 404 page but it's working perfectly in the local environment. I tested it and the hash router it's working in production but it adds a # hash symbol in the URL and I don't want to use this hash in the URL.

Comment: Could you add some log errors or a screenshot to help understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the the `#` change your Router from `HashRouter` to `BrowserRouter`:

```js
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

You can find examples and more details here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter